# Why does this RegionIntersection return EmptyRegion?

Tags: functions, regions

Why does the first one return `EmptyRegion[2]` while the second one works?
I expected the result is `Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]` as the second one.

```
RegionIntersection[
 Polygon[{{-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}}], 
 Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]]
```

[image]

```
RegionIntersection[Polygon[{{-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {-1, 0}}], 
 Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]]
```

[image]

Aslo how does EmptyRegion is defined?
I read the docs but still not quite clear.
It seems like a point is not empty in R but empty in R2.

How would I define a polygon region like above but without the boundary?

Comment: On `V12` I got the output `Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]` from the first one; see [`image`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV1Ym.png)

Comment: @bmf that is strange. Mine is "12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"

Comment: thanks for letting me know. Mine is `12.0.0`. Maybe others can check on other versions. If nobody checks, I will run a check on `13.0.0` in the morning

Comment: got the same output as OP (`EmptyRegion[2]` and `Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]]`) on v13.0.0.0

Comment: I have v12.2.0 and the cloud results are the same as yours. v12.0 output is different.

Comment: Your first definition `Polygon` includes point `{-1,1}` twice! Perhaps that's the reason why first intersection fails?

Comment: Use `CanonicalizePolygon` to fix it. @UlrichNeumann is right.

Comment: `RegionEqual[Polygon[{{-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {-1, 0}}], 
 Polygon[{{-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}}]]`  is `True` indicate that it is a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ln1 = Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}];
pts0 = {{-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}}
p0 = Polygon@pts0
p1 = Polygon[{{-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {-1, 0}}]
p2 = CanonicalizePolygon[p0]
```

These are regions nevertheless:

```
RegionQ /@ {p0, p1, p2}
```

> {True, True, True}

but a proper polygon produces the desired results for `RegionIntersection`. The polygon `p1` you defined just happened to be a correct polygon with no repeating points.

```
RegionIntersection[#, ln1] & /@ {p0, p1, p2}
```

> {EmptyRegion[2], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}

Comment: Thanks, actually the first one had problem so I removed the repeating points. I thought the first one should work as well.

Comment: Frankly your question has not been answered. What I have is a workaround only. If something is recognized as a `Region` as I showed above, then it must play nice with other regions.